# Control WS2812B LEDs independently

Tags: led, led-strip, rgb, ws2812b

I am using three WS2812B LEDs in my PCB and are connected in series with each other. Is there a way that I can control each LED independently rather than controlling all three together? For example just turn on 2nd LED and turn off other two LEDs?
[image: Schematic]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is a way.

You just send new data packet to all LEDs, but with only the changes for the LEDs you want to change. Even if you don't want to change the other LEDs, you need to update their data because a new data packet must be sent.

Which means you likely need to store state of each LED in your program to update only state of one LED and send the updated data to all LEDs.